# Inheritance and virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual

I have a class Tableau with a virtual function updateCustom() and another basic function checkNeighbours().
I have another class derived from Tableau, JeuTaquin, that override updateCustom(). And inside updateCustom, I want to call checkNeighbours() but I get a error.

My two function inside my class Tableau :

```
template<class T>
void updateCustom(char input) //Virtual function in .h
{}

template<class T>
Case<T>* Tableau<T>::checkNeighbours(const Case<T> **&plateau, int i, int j) 
{
//No need to see what is inside this function
Case<T> *neighbours;
neighbours = new Case<T>[4];
for(int n = 0; n<taille;n++)
    neighbours[n] = nullptr;
if(i!=0)
    neighbours[0] = plateau[i-1][j];
if(j!=taille)
    neighbours[1] = plateau[i][j+1];
if(i!=taille)
    neighbours[2] = plateau[i+1][j];
if(j!=0)
    neighbours[3] = plateau[i][j-1];

return neighbours;
}
```

Then inside JeuTaquin (which derive from Tableau):

```
template<class T>
void JeuTaquin<T>::updateCustom(char input)
{
//Here is my function checkNeighbours that I want to call
    Case<T> *neighbours = Tableau<T>::checkNeighbours(Tableau<T>::plateau1, 2, 2);  

}
```

When I try to compile, I get :

```
JeuTaquin.cpp:54:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘JeuTaquin<int>::checkNeighbours(Case<int>**&, int, int)’
neighbours = Tableau<T>::checkNeighbours(Tableau<T>::plateau1, 2, 2);
JeuTaquin.cpp:54:71: note: candidate is:
In file included from JeuTaquin.h:5:0,
             from JeuTaquin.cpp:1:
Tableau.h:78:11: note: Case<T>* Tableau<T>::checkNeighbours(const Case<T>**&, int, int) [with T = int]
Case<T>* checkNeighbours(const Case<T> **&plateau, int i, int j);
Tableau.h:78:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Case<int>**’ to ‘const Case<int>**&’
```

I don't know why I can't recognize checkNeighbours inside my overrided updateCustom(). My include are OK and I even call a function from Tableau in the constructor of JeuTaquin and it works well ! Thank you for your help

EDIT : I declare my updateCustom function in Tableau.h like this :

```
virtual void updateCustom(char input);
```

Comment: How is `checkNeighbours` declared, public, private, or protected? If it's private, you can't access it from another class.

Comment: checkNeighbours is public

Comment: your `updateCustom` is looking weird, its template and non virtual and not clear if its even method or free function, can you add more code?

Comment: Is it a static method? You're calling it like it is.

Comment: Once I invented the missing classes, it compiled fine for me. VS2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's illegal to cast `Type**` to `const Type**`.

see http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html for an explanation as to why.

Comment: Throwing const correctness out of the window to fix a problem caused by the `**&` mess seems like a bad habit to me.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the reference. Maintaining const correctness when dealing with pointers to pointers is much harder than when dealing with regular pointers. The real problem is using pointers to pointers in the first place, but that's a different story.

Comment: @Frank : That's what I meant. Could use a std::vector of std::vectors or a std::array of std::arrays and have the same [ ][ ] access. But it would allow passing with a normal const reference. I'm not questioning your answer but his fix.